# Setting form field to required with custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that queries google maps api with the form field value (event_postcode). It needs to be a required field. Yet when the field is populated, and maps api (via manageEventsSrv.getPostcodeLocation()) returns a valid address, the forms submit button remains disabled, i.e. form is invalid.

My directive:

```
app.directive('geoLocatePostcode', ['manageEventsSrv', function(manageEventsSrv) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
            var valid = false;
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                if(value.length>=3){
                    manageEventsSrv.getPostcodeLocation(value+',uk').then(function(result){
                        valid = true;
                        scope.point = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude:result.lat,longitude:result.lng}); // parse.com geopoint
                        ctrl.$setValidity('locationNotFound', true);
                    }, function(result){                            
                        valid = false;
                        ctrl.$setValidity('locationNotFound', false);
                    });
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('locationNotFound', true);
                    valid = false;
                }
                return valid ? value : undefined;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Form field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First 4 Characters Only" ng-model="event_postcode" maxlength="4" name="event_postcode" required geo-locate-postcode>

<span data-ng-show="createEventForm.event_postcode.$error.locationNotFound">Location not found</span>

<button type="submit" class="button" ng-disabled="createEventForm.$invalid">Create</button>
```

I assume i am not implementing "required" properly when using a custom directive.

Comment: Do you have a ``form`` or ``ng-form`` around your html code? With the name ``createEventForm``?

Comment: I have a form tag with the name "createEventForm".

Comment: Maybe an issue with the digest cycle? Have you tried calling scope.$apply() in your promise's ``then`` method?

Comment: Gave it a go... "$digest already in progress" error

Comment: Do you have the 'novalidate' attribute on the form?

Comment: Yep. This is my form tag : `<form ng-submit="saveEvent(createEventForm.$valid)" name="createEventForm" ng-controller="EventController" novalidate>`

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting the validity on the input? `ctrl.$setValidity('locationNotFound', false);` => `elem.$setValidity('locationNotFound', false);`

Comment: Thats throwing this error : "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: Think i might have got to the bottom of this.... i needed to change `return valid ? value : undefined;` to `return valid ? value : false;`

Answer (score 0):

Think i might have got to the bottom of this.... i needed to change 
`return valid ? value : undefined;` to `return valid ? value : false;`